In a Penrose frame, $\Omega^2_2 = d\omega^2_2$
I’m trying to understand why $\Omega^2_2 = d\omega^2_2$ in the setup of Ivo Terek’s notes page 12, proof of item (iii). The setup is the following. Let $(M^2, g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian surface with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and connection 1-forms $\omega^b_a$ and curvature 2-forms $\Omega^b_a$ of $\nabla$ relative to frame $E_a$ defined by
$$ \nabla_X E_a = \omega^b_a(X)E_b\qquad\text{and}\qquad R^{\nabla}(X,Y)E_a = \Omega^b_a(X,Y)E_b.$$
Finally, fix a Penrose frame $(E_1, E_2)$, i.e. one in which both $E_1$ and $E_2$ are lightlike sections of the tangent bundle and $g(E_1, E_2) = 1$.
Apparently, in this case the second structure equations $\Omega = d\omega + \omega\wedge\omega$ simplifies for the component $\Omega_2^2$ but I don’t see how entirely. I have:
$$\Omega_2^2 = d\omega_2^2 + \omega^2_1\wedge\omega^1_2 + \omega^2_2\wedge\omega^2_2$$
The second term on the RHS vanishes because in a Penrose frame lowering or raising an index amounts to replacing it by the other one, so $\omega^1_2 =\omega_{22}$ and $\omega_{22}=0$ by compatibility with the metric $\omega_{ij} + \omega_{ji} = 0$. However, how do I see that the term $\omega^2_2\wedge\omega^2_2$ vanishes as well?

Aren’t you just wedging the same 1-form with itself?

Maybe it’s not the fact that it is a $1$-form that matters but that it is a scalar-valued form wedged with itself. After all, $\omega \wedge \omega \neq 0$. Correct?

Yes $\omega\wedge\omega$ doesn’t necessarily vanish because these are matrix-valued 1-forms, but $\omega^2_{,,2}$ is a scalar-valued 1-form so wedging with itself gives $0$.
